Как найти символ(символы string) в List<T>, передать список найденных результатов в другой List<T>, и найденный символ подчеркнуть и показать в Lable
вечер, или ночь. Xamarin.Forms. Ищу решение. У меня есть List. Использую SearchBar, чтобы найти в этом List введенное поисковое слово(независимо от регистра).И мне надо, чтобы найденное слово потом в Label выделялось Жирный шрифтом или Подчеркиванием. Этот List потом идет в CollectionView. DateGroupListFull - это полный список. DateGroupList - это список с которым работаем, который отображается в UI.
 /* RealTime поиск */
 public void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (this.DateGroupListFull.Count != 0)
     {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
         {
             DateGroupList = DateGroupListFull.Where(x => 
             x.Name.ToUpper().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToUpper())).ToList();
             DateGroupList.ForEach(x => x.Name = x.Name.Replace(e.NewTextValue.ToUpper(), "* NEW TEXT?*"));
             var qw = DateGroupList;
         }
         else
         {
             DateGroupList = DateGroupListFull;
         }
     }
 }

